# NuSMV passes wrong specification

Tags: logic, temporal, ctl, nusmv

I am new to NuSMV and CTL and was trying simple Examples. I have 3 states A, B, and C and there is a transition from A-> B

I modeled it in NuSMV and want to check if there is any execution path from B to A. Eventhough I have not defined such transition, The Specification gives me counter example.

```
Module main
VAR
state:{a,b};
ASSIGN
init(state):=a;
next(state):=b;
SPEC !EF(state=a -> state=c)
SPEC !EF(state=b -> state=a)
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong in this?

how do i write specification for "is A reachable from B?" - this should return false as there is no transition defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* your code example was not working on my machine, it reported some *syntactic errors*, so I have actually changed it to look like this:

```
MODULE main ()
VAR
  state : {a,b,c};

ASSIGN
  init(state):=a;
  next(state):=b;
```

---

**Comments on your approach.**
The property `SPEC !EF(state=a -> state=c)` can be read as:

> it is not true that there exists a path starting from the initial state such that sooner or later the logic condition `state=a -> state=c` is `true`.

The condition `state = a -> state = c` is `true` for all states such that `state != a` only, because there exists no state in which the conditions `state = a` and `state = c` can hold at the same time.

If you run *NuSMV*, you are given the following counter-example:

```
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i test.smv; go; check_property
-- specification !(EF (state = a -> state = c))  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: CTL Counterexample 
Trace Type: Counterexample 
-> State: 1.1 <-
  state = a
-> State: 1.2 <-
  state = b
```

In state `1.2` the variable `state` is equal to `b`, therefore `state = a -> state = c` is `true` and `!EF(state = a -> state = c)` is violated.

Similar considerations hold for the property `SPEC !EF(state=b -> state=a)`.

---

**One-Step Reachability.**
If you want to check that there exists no *one-step* **transition** from a state in which `state = a` holds to a state in which `state = c` holds, then you can use the following property:

```
SPEC AG (state = a -> AX state != c)
```

This reads:

> for all states, that can be reached following all execution paths starting from all initial states, the *CTL* property `state = a -> AX state != c` is **always verified**. Such property says that, if in the current state `state = a`, then it is **necessarily** the case that in all possible *immediate next states* the value of `state` is different from `c`.

If we check such property with *NuSMV*, we find out that it is verified:

```
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i test.smv; go; check_property
-- specification AG (state = a -> AX state != c)  is true
```

A similar example holds for the other property that you want to encode.

---

**Path Reachability.** If you want to check that there exists no **path**, formed by an *arbitrary* and *variable* number of *intermediate transitions*, that reaches a state in which `state = c` holds, starting from a state in which `state = a` holds, then the encoding is slightly different:

```
SPEC AG (state = a -> AX AG state != c)
```

This reads:

> for all states, that can be reached following all executions paths starting from all initial states, the *CTL* property `state = a -> AX AG state != c` is **always verified**. Such property is `true` for all states `s'` s.t.
>
> - `state != a` in `s'`
>
> or
>
> - `state = a` in `s'`, and `state != c` for all reachable states `s''` on all the outgoing paths that start at `s'`

If we check such property with *NuSMV*, we find that it is verified:

```
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i test.smv; go; check_property
-- specification AG (state = a -> AX (AG state != c))  is true
```

---

To better outline the difference among the *two encodings*, I'll drop here a  *model example* on which the *first property* is `false` but the second one is `true`:

```
MODULE main ()
VAR
  state : {a,b,c};

ASSIGN
  init(state):=a;
  next(state) := case
     state = a : b;
     state = b : c;
     TRUE : state;
    esac;

SPEC AG (state = a -> AX state != c)
SPEC AG (state = a -> AX AG state != c)
```

If you run *NuSMV* over this example, the output is the following one:

```
NuSMV > reset; read_model -i test.smv; go; check_property
-- specification AG (state = a -> AX state != c)  is true
-- specification AG (state = a -> AX (AG state != c))  is false
-- as demonstrated by the following execution sequence
Trace Description: CTL Counterexample 
Trace Type: Counterexample 
-> State: 1.1 <-
  state = a
-> State: 1.2 <-
  state = b
-> State: 1.3 <-
  state = c
```

Obviosly, if the *first* property is found to be `false`, then the *second* property must necessarily be `false` as well.

---

**K-Steps Reachability.**
The *one-step reachability encoding* can be generalised to reachability in **exact** *k* steps by increasing the number of `AX` in the formula:

```
SPEC AG (state = a -> AX state != c)       -- state != c after 1 transition
SPEC AG (state = a -> AX AX state != c)    -- state != c after 2 transitions
SPEC AG (state = a -> AX AX AX state != c) -- state != c after 3 transitions
SPEC AG (state = a -> AX ... state != c)   -- state != c after 1 + |...| transitions
```

---

**ETA:**

In this use-case scenario, the property

```
SPEC AG (state = a -> AX AG state != c)
```

could be simplified to

```
SPEC AG (state = a -> AG state != c)
```

and, *apparently*, it would still work.

However, there is a reason why I did not do it: there is a *subtle semantic* difference among the two encodings, and even though the latter can be used to verify a *reachability* property in some cases, the former *encoding* is **more robust** since it more closely *matches* the actual *semantics* of the *reachability* problem. **e.g.** the template `B_COND_1 -> AG B_COND_2` fails miserably whenever `B_COND_2 := !B_COND_1`, because for any state `s'` that verifies the premise `B_COND_1` the conclusion `AG B_COND_2` --which can be rewritten as `AG !B_COND_1`-- cannot possibly hold; prepending `AX`to the conclusion adds one level of indirection, and it is more correct because the *conclusion* should only be required to hold starting from the *next states* in the execution tree.

---

**ETA #2:**

You write:

> how do i write specification for "is A reachable from B?" - this should return false as there is no transition defined

A property that returns `false` when there is no *path* from `state = b` to `state = a`, is the following:

```
SPEC AG (state = b -> EF state = a)
```

If you want to **verify** that it is *never the case that `state = a` is reachable from `state = b`*, then this is actually a **bad idea** for two reasons:

- if the property is verified, you are not returned a *witness counter-example* for the *execution trace* s.t. `state = a` is reachable from `state = b`, and therefore you are left on your own to determine why this is the case on your model
- if the property is `false`, the tool would need to list all of the *(possibly exponentially many)* paths starting from `state = b` such that `state = a` can not be reached.

For these reasons I actually encoded the reachability problem the other way around, returning `true` when `state = a` is not reachable from `state = b` and `false` + *single counter-example* otherwise.